# Poincaré inequation

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded Lipschitz domain, $C>0$ prove that $\forall u\in H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$:
$||u||_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C||D^2u||_{L^2(\Omega)}$.

I shall use two Poincaré inequations. Ansatz: Known $||u||_{L^2}\leq C ||\nabla u||_{L^2}$ and $||u||^2_{H^1}\leq C (||u||^2_{L^2}+(⨍u)^2)$.

Definition: $||u||^2_{H^2}=||u||^2_{L^2}+||Du||^2_{L^2}+||D^2u||^2_{L^2}$. I literally have no idea how to use known Poincaré inequations... Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $u\in H^1_0\cap H^2$ tells you that your first Poincaré inequality (the one *without* the average) is the one you want to use. This tells you that $\| u\|_{H^2}^2\lesssim \| \nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \| D^2 u\|_{L^2}^2$.

Throughout I'll assume that $u\in H_0^1\cap C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ (the general case is an approximation argument).
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2\, dx = -\int_\Omega u \Delta u \, dx,
$$
since the boundary terms vanish. On the other hand, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
\left| \int_\Omega u\Delta u\, dx \right| \leq \| u\|_{L^2}\| D^2 u\|_{L^2} \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\| u\|_{L^2}^2 + \dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}\| D^2 u\|_{L^2}^2,
$$
for any $\epsilon>0$ (this follows from $ab\leq a^2/2+b^2/2$).

Now if $C_1$ is the constant in the Poincaré inequality we get
$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\| u\|_{L^2}^2 + \dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}\| D^2 u\|_{L^2}^2 \leq \dfrac{C_1^2\epsilon}{2}\| \nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}\| D^2 u\|_{L^2}^2,
$$
and so, if $\epsilon<1/C_1^2$, we get
$$
\| \nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 \leq \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\| D^2 u\|_{L^2}^2.
$$

Comment: With a $C^2$ instead of $C$, but yeah, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: I got another question: why and when did you use $\Delta u$ and when $D^2u$. Where the exact difference?